# Change If Statement to display none if text not number

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pull through a value from the dataLayer to fire a piece of HTML. All pulling through fine, however if the value is 'undefined' rather than an actual number I don't want it to fire.

How can I solve this? Tried everything but it's returning true/false rather than not firing.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 0, len = dataLayer.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (dataLayer[i].event === "productView")
            var viewed = dataLayer[i].P2;
    }


    function isOnScreen(element) {
        var curPos = element.offset();
        var curTop = curPos.top - $(window).scrollTop();
        var screenHeight = $(window).height();
        return (curTop > screenHeight) ? false : true;
    }

    var intervalId = setInterval(function () {
        var addtocart = $('#add-to-cart');
        if (isOnScreen(addtocart) === true) {
            $('.product-image.main-image').before("<div id='social-overlay' style='color: #fff;text-transform: uppercase;font-family: Muli,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 11px; font-weight: 800;background: #867dae; opacity: 0.8; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; position: absolute;z-index: 1; width: 100%;'>" + viewed + " people viewed item in the last 24 hours</div>")
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#social-overlay').fadeOut(1000);
            }, 7000);

            clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: On which line does the error occur? Please add a comment in the code.

Comment: Please calrify: What does "to pull through a value" mean? What does "to fire a piece of HTML" mean? Which value are you referring to? There is no variable named "value", so that could mean anything.

Comment: The viewed variable is supposed to pull through the value of product views - which is working. However sometimes this value is 'undefined' rather than 2,3,4 (or any numerical value). When it's undefined I don't want it to show, only when it's a number do I want it to appear.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not clarify anything. "to pull through" is not any terminology I am familiar with. The same goes for "to fire a piece of HTML". Again, which value are you referring to? What is the variable name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the variable 'viewed' is undefined in the setInterval function you have and add the html value using before function only if the viewed is valid.

```
    var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    var addtocart = $('#add-to-cart');
    if ( typeof viewed !== 'undefined' && isOnScreen(addtocart) === true) {
       $('.product-image.main-image').before("<div id='social-overlay' style='color: #fff;text-transform: uppercase;font-family: Muli,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 11px; font-weight: 800;background: #867dae; opacity: 0.8; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; position: absolute;z-index: 1; width: 100%;'>" + viewed + " people viewed item in the last 24 hours</div>") ;   
      setTimeout(function(){
          $('#social-overlay').fadeOut(1000);
      }, 7000);

      clearInterval(intervalId);  
  } 
  }, 500);
```